# Gradle getting stuck at assembleDebug

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I've been working on a Flutter project for the past month. I've been able to run this code successfully up to this point but now it no longer works. I believe this happened after my package manager updated Flutter (running Arch Linux).

The output of `flutter run --verbose`:

```
➜  imperium2 git:(master) ✗ flutter run --verbose
[  +15 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +17 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 8735ab1e35346ae20b6c347d259b07b1589756a5
[        ] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.15.1-36-g8735ab1e35
[   +3 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/master
[        ] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +2 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] /home/vlad/.cache/yay/flutter-git/flutter
[  +26 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] master
[  +16 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +15 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:1
[  +11 ms] /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +28 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +48 ms] Found plugin file_picker at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-1.4.3+2/
[  +19 ms] Found plugin path_provider at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.0/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin permission_handler at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-4.2.0+hotfix.3/
[   +9 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.4.1/
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_macos-0.0.1+2/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_web-0.1.1/
[  +26 ms] Found plugin file_picker at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-1.4.3+2/
[  +10 ms] Found plugin path_provider at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.0/
[        ] Found plugin permission_handler at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-4.2.0+hotfix.3/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.4.1/
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_macos-0.0.1+2/
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_web at /home/vlad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_web-0.1.1/
[  +27 ms] Generating /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +25 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[   +6 ms] Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +15 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
[   +8 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           02-07 15:54:57.882 I/.screenrecorde( 5791): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
[   +6 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[        ] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 logcat -v time -T 02-07 15:54:57.882
[   +8 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.5-5949299
           Installed as /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +1 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[   +4 ms] Building APK
[  +11 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +1 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +1 ms] Using gradle from /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/android/gradlew.
[        ] /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/android/gradlew mode: 33261 rwxr-xr-x.
[   +5 ms] executing: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[  +38 ms] Exit code 0 from: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_202-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b49-5587405, mixed mode)
[   +3 ms] executing: [/home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/android/] /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true -Ptarget=/home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/lib/main.dart
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root -Ptarget-platform=android-x86 assembleDebug
[+3416 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 6 busy and 1 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+4795 ms] > Task :permission_handler:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :file_picker:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :path_provider:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
```

It gets stuck at the last line. I've tried waiting up to half an hour without it moving.

The output of `./gradlew assembleDebug --debug`:

```
16:13:57.502 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
16:13:57.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' started
16:13:57.503 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.RecordingBuildListener] Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug in app Starting
16:13:57.520 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter] Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' into context took 0.006 secs.
16:13:57.537 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :file_picker:clean' started
16:13:57.537 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
16:13:57.537 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
16:13:57.537 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
16:13:57.537 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :file_picker:clean'
16:13:57.537 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :file_picker:clean' completed
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :app:clean' started
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :app:clean'
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :app:clean' completed
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher:clean' started
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
16:13:57.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher:clean'
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher:clean' completed
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher_macos:clean' started
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher_macos:clean'
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher_macos:clean' completed
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher_web:clean' started
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher_web:clean'
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :url_launcher_web:clean' completed
16:13:57.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :path_provider:clean' started
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :path_provider:clean'
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :path_provider:clean' completed
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :permission_handler:clean' started
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Realize task :permission_handler:clean'
16:13:57.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Realize task :permission_handler:clean' completed
16:13:57.582 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskSnapshotter] Snapshotting property dependenciesFiles$1 (Output) for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'
16:13:57.582 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskSnapshotter] Snapshotting property outputDirectory (Output) for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'
16:13:57.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep] Implementation for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug': FlutterTask_Decorated@b92c707a25bb987ce61e4078c00cc401
16:13:57.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep] Additional implementations for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug': [FlutterTask_Decorated@b92c707a25bb987ce61e4078c00cc401]
16:13:57.588 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep] Fingerprinting property sourceFiles for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'
16:13:57.588 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep] Caching disabled for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' because:
  Build cache is disabled
16:13:57.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Determining if task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' is up-to-date
16:13:57.589 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
16:13:57.590 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep] Ensuring parent directory exists for property dependenciesFiles$1 at /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_build.d
16:13:57.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep] Ensuring directory exists for property outputDirectory at /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug
16:13:57.600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
16:13:57.611 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute build for :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' started
16:13:57.634 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'command '/opt/flutter/bin/flutter''. Working directory: /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2 Command: /opt/flutter/bin/flutter --quiet assemble --depfile /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_build.d --output /home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug -dTargetFile=lib/main.dart -dTargetPlatform=android -dBuildMode=debug debug_android_application
16:13:57.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Environment for process 'command '/opt/flutter/bin/flutter'': {PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/home/vlad/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/android-ndk:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin:/opt/cuda/bin:/opt/flutter/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl, XAUTHORITY=/home/vlad/.Xauthority, LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.UTF-8, XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/vlad/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share, LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus, ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE, QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0, AUTOJUMP_SOURCED=1, MAIL=/var/spool/mail/vlad, MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins, COLORTERM=truecolor, LC_COLLATE=nb_NO.UTF-8, SESSION_MANAGER=local/Acheron:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/54201,unix/Acheron:/tmp/.ICE-unix/54201, LOGNAME=vlad, PWD=/home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/android, PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket, XCURSOR_THEME=breeze_cursors, LANGUAGE=en_US, WINDOWID=88080395, KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5, SHELL=/usr/bin/fish, TERMINFO=/usr/lib/kitty/terminfo, ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/opt/android-ndk, QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=DVI-D-0=1;HDMI-0=1;DP-0=1;DP-1=1;DP-2=1;DP-3=1;DP-4=1;DP-5=1;, OLDPWD=/home/vlad/Cloud/Programming/Android/imperium2/android, ANDROID_NDK=/opt/android-ndk, KDE_FULL_SESSION=true, GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module:appmenu-gtk-module, SSH_ASKPASS=ksshaskpass, XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session5, XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE, AUTOJUMP_ERROR_PATH=/home/vlad/.local/share/autojump/errors.log, SHLVL=3, LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=iHD, TERMINAL=konsole, LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.UTF-8, FLUTTER_HOME=/opt/flutter, KDE_SESSION_UID=1000, TERM=xterm-kitty, LANG=en_US.UTF-8, XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0, XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11, XDG_SESSION_ID=7, DISPLAY=:0, XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user, XCURSOR_SIZE=24, UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1, DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/plasma, CUDA_PATH=/opt/cuda, USER=vlad, DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=Acheron;1581083130;666329;54215_TIME2585617, LC_NUMERIC=nb_NO.UTF-8, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket, XDG_SEAT=seat0, XDG_VTNR=1, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000, KITTY_WINDOW_ID=1, HOME=/home/vlad, HG=/usr/bin/hg}
16:13:57.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
16:13:57.643 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command '/opt/flutter/bin/flutter'.
16:13:57.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
16:13:57.650 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command '/opt/flutter/bin/flutter''
16:13:57.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
16:14:00.209 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] 
16:14:00.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
16:14:00.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:00.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:00.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:00.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:00.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:00.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:02.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18270146560}
16:14:02.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18270146560}
16:14:02.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 1017643008}
16:14:07.958 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18205433856}
16:14:07.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18205433856}
16:14:07.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 1017643008}
16:14:10.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
16:14:10.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:10.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:10.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:10.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:10.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:10.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:12.958 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18308898816}
16:14:12.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18308898816}
16:14:12.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 1017643008}
16:14:17.958 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18305212416}
16:14:17.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33535705088, Free: 18305212416}
16:14:17.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 1017643008}
16:14:20.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
16:14:20.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:20.209 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:20.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:20.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:20.210 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
16:14:20.211 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

The lines at the bottom, waiting for shared lock, locking, releasing and emitting memory status events keep repeating forever. This is not the full output, I only added the output for `:app:compileFlutterBuildDebug` considering the output is over 500k lines long.

Output of `flutter doctor --verbose`

```
/opt/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.15.2-pre.36, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.15.2-pre.36 at /opt/flutter
    • Framework revision 8735ab1e35 (8 hours ago), 2020-02-06 23:36:59 -0800
    • Engine revision f34bc65bee
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.7.0 b3396cbdca)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /opt/android-sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /opt/android-sdk
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Things I've tried**

- Deleting .gradle in my home directory
- Enabling "offline work" for Gradle
- Adding `org.gradle.parallel=true` to `gradle.properties`
- Switching Gradle version from 5.6.2 to 5.6.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hit the same issue here, turns out downgrading the linux kernel to `5.4.15-arch1-1` from `5.5.2-arch1-1` makes it work again.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Odd that the new kernel breaks this though.

Comment: @Raghap if you still have the project, it will be a good idea to open an issue on the flutter GitHub page

Comment: Same issue here. Solved by downgrading the kernel. Where should we report this?

Comment: This worked for me too. I downgraded from 5.5.2-1 to 5.4.18-1, EDIT: Looks to have been reported: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40589