# "flutter run" gets stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug"

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

I updated Flutter to the latest stable version today - `1.12.13+hotfix.7` (I was running 1.12.13+hotfix.6 before). When I tried to run my project in vs code with `flutter run` it always gets stuck at `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug`:

[image]

Have anyone experienced the same issue?

Here is the output of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[georgi@georgi-pc Line-up-Generator]$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at /home/georgi/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (2 weeks ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/georgi/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • MI 8 • 62fb6fd8 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I have to point out that I have tried running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` but it gets stuck at 25%

[image]

Note: I am on Manjaro 18.1.5

**UPDATE**:
There seems to be an issue with Dart SDK: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49185#issuecomment-589968058

Comment: In most cases it is best to just copy and paste the output so that everyone has a easier time working with it instead of posting images.

Comment: Yes, good point. I have replaced `flutter doctor -v` output with text

Comment: Can you install flutter plugin in android studio first

Comment: I had some build issues recently due to dependency issues (it also got stuck, without giving any warning). Do these problems persist when you try to run a completely fresh/new Flutter app?

Comment: @Dev I will try that when I get home. Tom, I remember trying that with `flutter create --androidx -t app /path/to/app` and it was running fine after

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116341/gradle-getting-stuck-at-assembledebug

Comment: Thanks @PrathikJain! I actually updated the kernel to `5.5` recently but I thought that the problem is somewhere else. I will test later today if downgrading to an older version  (i.e. 5.2) will fix the issue.

Comment: @PrathikJain that solved it! Downgrading to kernel `5.4.17-1` solved the issue! T (it's a LTS so I should've staid with this one anyway, I updated it for no reason). The Flutter team probably tests against LTS versions of the kernel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been resolved upstream. If you want to consume it you will have to switch to the `master` channel (for now. It will arrive in the `stable` channel at some point) by running

```
flutter channel master
```

After running that, I was able to build my apk just fine on Linux 5.5

Comment: I'm on windows and I did that, and still it gets stuck

Answer (score 5):

> `flutter clean` worked for me

I had the same issue. I tried so many solutions and finally found on [`Github.`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47392) Try this command in the terminal.

Comment: At the time I did try this command and it didn't help me, perhaps in your situation, it was a different problem. With me, it was the kernel version that was throwing things off and required a change in the flutter framework

Comment: Okay, no problem. If someone having Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... takes too much time or ran out of heap space. So, they can use this command.

Comment: I was stuck and i used this command. While this command was still under processing, application got executed on my phone. Now i am not sure if this command made it to do so or it was just a co-incidence.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it.
I ran flutter doctor --android-licenses as sudo.
I used the whole path, don't know if that's necessary though.

For example I did it like that:
sudo /home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --android-licenses

After that everything worked.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... did you try that with Kernel 5.5?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev yeah I did that. It works just fine on my laptop.

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev I strongly recomment to not follow my advice. By the time I wrote my answer everything somehow worked. The next day I had massive problems and today I figured out that it's the kernels fault. Please excuse me if you followed my advice and wasted your time. :(

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I did not have a chance to try your suggestion yet, thank you for lettime me know. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

I tried every answer I found about it, but none of them worked.

Finally I fixed it by deleting the Android Virtual Device I had and creating a new one. In my case looks like it was a problem with the android emulator rather than a flutter bug.