# when ever I try to run my Flutter program, it gets stuck at “Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug”

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, flutter, android-sdk-tools

whenever I try to run in on an Emulator or on a real device, it get stuck at `“Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug”` and the entire computer just freezes and get stuck, and the only way out is to hard reboot it.

I'm using an Asus laptop ( windows 10 ), with 16GB ram.

`flutter --version` gives: (when I try `flutter upgrade` it gives same result and says I have the latest version)

```
Flutter 1.20.0-1.0.pre.42 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 401690a64f (2 days ago) • 2020-06-12 19:45:48 -0700
Engine • revision 965fbbed17
Tools • Dart 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.0.dev 2b917f5b6a)
```

when I run `flutter doctor` I get this output in the terminal: ***UPDATED***

```
   C:\Users\Lidor>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.20.0-1.0.pre.42, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

when I run `flutter doctor -v` I get this output:

```
C:\Users\Lidor>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.20.0-1.0.pre.42, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.0-1.0.pre.42 at D:\Study\P.Languages\Flutter\flutter_windows_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision 401690a64f (2 days ago), 2020-06-12 19:45:48 -0700
    • Engine revision 965fbbed17
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.0.dev 2b917f5b6a)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at D:\Lidor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2
    • Flutter plugin version 38.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 192.5728.98

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I also tried to run `flutter channel master` as it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614364/8405296) and also everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug)

Comment: Have you updated any of the native android files (under android dir)? Added any dependancies, changed anything?

Comment: nope, all stayed the same from when it did worked smoothly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter App stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug)

Comment: no, @Nuts already gave this link and we tried it, but it didn't helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of reasons why it's happening: Did not accept android-licenses, incompatible version of sdk/flutter,   Windows Firewall etc.

If you haven't tried:

Updated file android/app/build.gradle with

`compileSdkVersion 29`

Run:
`flutter clean`

Otherwise check [Flutter App stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug)

Or if your `Android license status unknown.`

[Android Studio installs without sdkmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager)
Uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages and you'll see Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1.
and then `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: tried running flutter clean and tried turning off the firewall as the link you provided suggested, none helped

Comment: Have you tried other methods in the link? Or smth like disabling antivirus?

Comment: disabled antivirus not working, looking now at the rest of the solutions they gave

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager and dont't forget to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses
` with `y`

Comment: I accepted everything, now the doctor doesn't find anything wrong, yet when I run the program it still get everything stuck :-(

Comment: Flutter doctor says that Android license status unknown.hmmz

Comment: the doctor says the licence is fine, all mark V, but it still gets stuck

Comment: Could you update ur flutter doctor output? In there it says that `Android license status unknown.`

Answer (score 0):

in my case I just run flutter upgrade

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).